# ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at line 8 01403. 00000 - "no data found"

Tags: oracle, plsql

Normally this basic If statement should return data but I don't understand, where I have made a mistake. (CustNo is char(8).) I think the problem occurs because of V_Id. In an usual select statement with this Custno='C2388597', I can have the data.But when it is in If statement, It gives the ORA-01403 Error code.

Thank you in advance for your Support...

```
Declare 

  V_Id Deneme_Customer.Custno%type;
  V_Custbal Deneme_Customer.Custbal%Type;
  v_situation Deneme_Customer.Custbal_Situation%type;

Begin
  Select Custno, Custbal, Custbal_Situation Into V_Id, V_Custbal, V_Situation
    From Deneme_Customer Where V_Id ='&no';
  
  If (V_Custbal>=20 And V_Custbal<=100) Then 
    V_Situation:='Es tut mir sehr leid';
  Elsif (V_Custbal>=101 And V_Custbal<=1000) Then 
    V_Situation:='Guuuut';
  Elsif (V_Custbal>1000) Then 
    V_Situation:='Sehr Guuuut';
  Else Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Falsche Eingabe');

  End If;
  
  update Deneme_Customer set Custbal_Situation=v_situation where Custno=V_Id;

end;`
```

Comment: What does `BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '"&no;"' ); END;` output? Are there any trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `v_id`,which is a local variable, is `Custno`,which is a column of your table, on the 8th line.

An exception handling might still be needed for non-matching values for `Custno` vs. `'&no'`  such as

```
Begin
  Select Custno, Custbal, Custbal_Situation Into V_Id, V_Custbal, V_Situation
    From Deneme_Customer 
   Where Custno = '&no';
  Exception When no_data_found then null;
 End;
```

Comment: I have added the exception block, and now I don't have any error message but also I can not have any result. it should return 1 row data. And Custno and V_id have CHAR(8) type.

Comment: Did you replace `V_Id` with `Custno` within the where condition @dwh_asil ? Btw, excuse me, relised that custno is not of type integer, so keep the quotes.

Comment: No problem. Thx for your all support. I have just replaced them,Unfortunately there isnt't any error but also there isn't  any update too. In the meantime I have modified the Custno column as Varchar2, but it didn't change anything too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PL/SQL to determine what **custbal_situation** should be set to, you can do it easily with a simple update statement like this one:

```sql
UPDATE deneme_customer
   SET custbal_situation =
           CASE
               WHEN custbal >= 20 AND custbal <= 100 THEN 'Es tut mir sehr leid'
               WHEN custbal >= 101 AND custbal <= 1000 THEN 'Guuuut'
               WHEN custbal > 1000 THEN 'Sehr Guuuut'
           END
 WHERE custbal >= 20;
```

If you want to modify it to only affect one customer, just add that to the where clause.

Then to see any customers that would not have their value set, you can find them with a query like this one

```sql
SELECT custno, custbal, custbal_situation
  FROM deneme_customer
 WHERE custbal < 20;
```

Comment: Thx for your support. I know I can do it in many ways but here I am trying/learning to use If Statement and Statements with Variable. Because of this reason I did it a little bit complex.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you may not have any row matching  Where V_Id ='&no', just to test it do a select count from the table Where V_Id ='&no'and check the count.

ALso is your V_Id a unique column, if not then you need to handle in your error handler the case when you fine more than one row matching your where clause.

```
exception 
  when no_data_found then
    <handle apppropriately>
  when TOO_MANY_ROWS then
    <handle apppropriately>
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
      ('Unknown error');
end
```

Comment: V_id is an unique column, and any row is matching where v_id=no. It is the same when I have retrieved SELECT COUNT. With the Exception blocks I don't take any error but also still nothing is changed in the table.